# Is the new keyword not executable?

Tags: java

In java how come at the top of the class we can initalize memory like so

```
public Class blahh{

private String s = new String("Hi");

public static void main(String args[]){}
}
```

Why is this legal, is not new key word executable code?

What if I replaced the private String s.... with a method call instead. Would it get executed?

Comment: Yes, the constructor will run whenever the class is instantiated. If the declaration were `static`, then it would run whenever the class was loaded into memory.

Comment: @Kon: whenever the class was loaded into memory. or only once? What about inherited and non-inherited classes? Do they load separately?

Comment: Only once, for `static`.

Comment: And blahh inherits a default constructor from Object automatically

Comment: So can you have a method call in the same place as the declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a *field declarator*. It may include an *initializer*, which is a value assigned to the field. It's a sort of shorthand for doing the assignment inside the constructor.

Now, this sort of initializer may look natural to you:

```
private int myInt = 3;
```

But in fact, initializers can be expressions of any kind:

```
private int myInt = 9 / 3;
```

Here you already have a calculation. This is code that executes (well, it may be optimized away, but in theory, even if you didn't have any optimizer, this would work). It divides 9 by 3, and assigns the result to `myInt`.

What this actually tells the compiler is that when a new instance of this class is created, it should perform this calculation, and assign the value to the field, before proceeding with the body of the constructor.

So generally any kind of code that is allowed to be executed within the constructor, provided it can be expressed in one expression, can be assigned to the variable. Here is a little program:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    // Yes, you can call a method as a field initialization!
    private int myInt = myMethod();

    // The method performs a calculation end returns a value.
    private int myMethod() {
        return (int)Math.sqrt(9.0);
    }

    // Getter for the field
    public int getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        SimpleTest test = new SimpleTest();
        System.out.println( test.getMyInt());
    }

}
```

This program shows you that you can use a method in a field declarator. The program will print "3".